# how to disable mouse click in QSplashScreen

Tags: c++, qt

I create a class inherited of QSplashScreen, and try to override the mousePressEvent method, but when I click, hide the splash.

```
    class Splash : public QSplashScreen
    {
    public:
        Splash();
        ~Splash() override;
    protected:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) override;
    };
```

Comment: Override closeEvent.

Comment: I override closeEvent, the situation are the same :/

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.  Platform and `Qt` version may also be important.

Comment: How do you override those event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem before, hope this helps you
**Header File**

```
#ifndef MYSPLASH_H
#define MYSPLASH_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSplashScreen>

class MySplash : public QSplashScreen
{
public:
    MySplash(const QPixmap &pixmap = QPixmap(), Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    bool eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event);
};

#endif // MYSPLASH_H
```

**CPP File**

```
#include "mysplash.h"
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>
MySplash::MySplash(const QPixmap &pixmap, Qt::WindowFlags f)
{                
    this->setPixmap(pixmap);
    this->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MySplash::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(target)
    if((event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) ||
            (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) ||
            (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) ||
            (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) ||
            (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

In main.cpp you can add these lines

```
// Splash Screen
MySplash *splash = new MySplash(QPixmap(":/Images/SplashScreen.png"));
splash->show();
a.processEvents();

// Start the application
HomePage w;
w.showMaximized();

// Finish
splash->finish(&w);
delete splash;
a.processEvents();
return a.exec();
```