# Qt: QSplashScreen hiding when clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I'm rather a novice of Qt.
I started with the following code, almost taken [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplashscreen.html)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPixmap pixmap(":/image.pn");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
    splash.show();
    app.processEvents();

    QWidget widget;

    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &splash, &QWidget::close);
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &widget, &QWidget::show);

    return app.exec();
}
```

The intent is clear: I want to show a splash screen for 3 seconds and then I want my widget to appear. The problem is that I notice that clicking on the image shown by the splash screen it disappears. I would like to disable this behavior. *I know that this question has been asked many times, but none of the answers worked for me*

What I tried:

1. to install a filter to filter the events in a custom subclass of QSplashScreen, exactly like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610259/how-to-disable-mouse-click-in-qsplashscreen): with a click the splash screen is hiding;
2. Again to subclass QSplashScreen and overriding a mousePressEvent, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505454/how-do-i-disable-the-default-click-to-dismiss-behaviour-of-qsplashscreen), after the simple translation in C++. Again, as before, with a click, it disappears;
3. I install a event filter and let it log out the event it registered: as soon as I click into the splash screen I get:

   ```
   QEvent::WindowStateChange
   QEvent::Hide
   ```

and the splash screen disappears.

4. I tried to reset the windows flag, but again the same.

I know that the default behavior of QSplasScreen is precisely that one, but *it is possible to disable it*?

I'm using a Desktop kit, version 6.4.2, running on arch linux.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPixmap pixmap("c:\\Users\\queentest\\Downloads\\6533213052981721747.png");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
    splash.show();
    //app.processEvents();
    QThread::msleep(3000);
    QWidget widget;
    splash.close();
    widget.show();
    //QTimer::singleShot(3000, &splash, &QWidget::close);
    //QTimer::singleShot(3000, &widget, &QWidget::show);

    return app.exec();
}
```